# Change format of webform emails via hook

Tags: hooks, webforms

I'm trying to alter the output of webform submissions in emails. At the moment, I'm just looking for the correct function. I can see there is a hook to alter the rendered output, which is being hit, but it is not changing the output of the emails. Am I replacing the Theme function in the correct place?

```
function seven_webform_submission_render_alter(&$renderable) {
  $renderable['#theme'] = 'seven_webform_submission_table';
  dpm($renderable);
  kpr($renderable);
}

function  seven_webform_submission_table($node, $submission, $email, $format) {
  return 'test';
}
```

Comment: there is little confusion about query. what u actually want?

Answer (score 1):

The hook you are looking for is hook_mail_alter.

To modify webform submissions emails your code should look like:

```
function MYMODULE_mail_alter(&$message){
  if ($message['module'] == 'webform' && $message['key' == 'submission']){
    /*** Place your code here ***/
  }
}
```

This will alter just the webform submissions emails.

Comment: Your code is wrong wrongly formated, this is how it should look. function MYMODULE_custom_mail_alter(&$message){ if ($message['module'] == 'webform' && $message['key'] == 'submission'){ dpm($message); } }

Answer (score 1):

Read Documentation here that may help you.

[Customising the emails sent by webform](http://drupal.org/node/1337488)